Is this cardinality motivated theory of arithmetic synonymous with PA?
Logic: Strict Bi-sorted first order logic with equality,
Signature: $=; \in; ||$
, first sort written in lower case range over natural numbers, the second sort written in upper case range over sets of naturals, strict means the sorts are nonempty and disjoint. "$=$" has no syntactical restriction, "$\in$" only occurs syntactically from first to second sort, "$||$" is a total unary function symbol syntactically limited to occur only from second sort to first sort, denoting the cardinality of a set.
Extralogical Axioms:

Elements: $\forall x \exists Y: x=|Y|$
Define: $a < b \iff \exists X \exists Y \subsetneq X:    a=|Y| \land b=|X|$

Comprehension: $\forall n \exists! X \forall y \, (y \in X \leftrightarrow y \not > n \land \phi(y))$,
if "$X$" is not free in $\phi$.

Finiteness: $\forall n: n \not < n$

Actuation: $\forall X \forall a: a < |X| \to \exists Y \subsetneq X: a=|Y|$

Ordering: $X \neq \varnothing \to \exists y \in X \forall z \in X:   y \leq z$



Is this theory synonymous with $ \sf PA$.

It was suggested at ending paragraph of this answer to a prior posting of similarly motivated theory, that a theory similar to this but with Ordering holding over statements instead of sets would prove synonymous with $ \sf PA$. However, the question here is about if this can still be achieved with the single Ordering axiom.

What do you mean with "synonymous"?

@Wojowu, Two theories $U$ and $V$ are synonymous iff there are interpretations $K : U \to V$ and $M : V \to U$, such that $V$ proves that the composition $ K \circ M$ is the identity interpretation on $V$
and such that $U$ proves that the composition $M \circ K$ is the identity interpretation
on $U$. WHEN BI-INTERPRETABILITY IMPLIES SYNONYMY

I think you're going to need some kind of extensionality for this to possibly work.

You can prove the Ordering schema (ranging over classes) by applying your Comprehension axiom: if $\phi$ is satisfiable, then find any $x$ satisfying $\phi(x)$, construct $X={n\not>x : \phi(x)}$ via Comprehension, and find a minimum of $X$ via Ordering. Ordering+Actuation+Finiteness prove $<$ is a total order, so the minimum of X will minimally satisfy $\phi$. This technique is often in set theory for setlike wellorders. With this, you can perform the same interpretation as in your previous theory to obtain $\sf{PA}$.

@JamesEHanson well the idea is that all sets are finite so per comprehension they'll be extensional.

@ZuhairAl-Johar Ah, I see. That's why you have the $\exists !$ quantifier in there. I'm concerned that it won't be enough to ensure extensionality in non-standard models.

@JamesEHanson, yes, perhaps its not enough, I'm not sure, so just in a case, it would be prudent to add Extensionality outright in the usual manner as in ZF.

I managed to prove the $\sf{PA}$ axioms and that all sets are bounded, so you don't need to include Extensionality (it's a theorem). Your theory is equivalent to the two-typed theory of $\sf{PA}$ augmented by Extensional finite sets. There's a subtlety in the fact that we have two types, though. $\sf{PA}$ only has one type, so we can't get synonymy unless there's a canonical way to merge the sets into the numbers. If you include strict sorting, we can get synonymy via Ackermann's bijection and by fitting the two types into the evens and odds respectively.

@JadeVanadium, the two sorted PA is synonymous I think with the one sorted, perhaps use Lumsdaine's proof of synonymy between Counting theory and PA. Which use the evens odds strategy.

@ZuhairAl-Johar Oh sorry, I had skipped over the part where you said you were using strict typing. Yes, you do indeed get synonymy.

Yes, this theory is synonymous with $\sf{PA}$. In particular, it's equivalent to a counting theory which was proven synonymous to $\sf{PA}$. I'll prove the equivalence by recovering the $\sf{PA}$ axioms and proving that all sets are bounded.

Lemma: $a<b<c \implies a<c$ 
proof: By definition of $<$, find $Y\subsetneq Z$ with $|Y|=b$ and $|Z|=c$. Now $a<|Y|$ so apply Actuation to find $X\subsetneq Y$ with $|X|=a$. It follows that $X\subsetneq Z$, therefore $a<c$. $\square$
Lemma: $a\leq b \lor b\leq a$ 
proof: Assuming $\neg(a\leq b)$, construct $X=\{m\not> a : m=a\lor m=b\}$ via Comprehension, and infer $X=\{a,b\}$ since we assumed $a\not<b$. Find a minimum $m\in X$ via Ordering, and since $\neg(a\leq b)$ then $m\neq a$ so $m=b$ and $b\leq a$. $\square$
Theorem: $(\exists x, \phi(x))\implies \exists(y:\phi),\forall(z:\phi), y\leq z$ 
proof: Supposing $\phi(x)$, construct $X=\{n\leq x : \phi(n)\}$ via Comprehension, and find $y\in X$ where $\forall(z\in X), y\leq z$ via Ordering. Now any $z$ obeying $\phi(z)$ either has $x\leq z$ so that $y\leq x \leq z$, or else $z\leq x$ so that $z\in X$ and $y\leq z$. Either way, $y\leq z$ as required. $\square$
From here, you can apply nearly the same exact proofs carried out on that answer you linked, with three modifications. Firstly, the set $\mathbb{N}$ cannot be constructed since it's unbounded, but it will be the universal class by consequence of your Finiteness axiom, so its role in the proofs is trivialized and can be eliminated. Secondly, any time we take a minimum of a possibly unbounded set, just consider it as taking the minimum of a class. This is fine since we proved the full Wellordering scheme. Finally, all theorems which invoke quantification on sets must be restricted to the bounded sets. None of those proofs ever rely on unbounded sets, and the bounded sets are closed under adjunction (the map $S\mapsto S\cup\{x\}$), so all the modified theorems should follow using identical proofs. This lets us define arithmetic and prove all the $\sf{PA}$ axioms. Finally, we can prove that all sets are bounded and thus extensional.
Theorem: $\forall S, \exists n, \forall(x\in S), x\leq n$ 
proof: By contradiction suppose $S$ is unbounded, then we prove by induction on $n$ that $S$ has a bounded subset of cardinality $n$. This is trivial for $n=0$ by using $\emptyset$. Assuming our claim holds at $n$, then we have bounded $Z\subseteq S$ where $|Z|=n$. Since $S$ is unbounded and $Z$ is bounded, we can find $x\in S$ where $Z\ll x$, hence $x\in S\setminus Z$. Letting $Z^+=Z\cup\{x\}$, we see $Z^+$ is a bounded subset of $S$, and moreover $|Z^+|=|Z|+1 = n+1$. This completes the induction. Now simply let $n=|S|+1$, then find a bounded subset $Z\subseteq S$ with $|Z|=n$. Since $Z$ is bounded and $S$ isn't, then $Z\subsetneq S$ and so $|Z|<|S|$, but now $|S|+1=n=|Z|<|S|$ implies $|S|+1<|S|$, a contradiction as expected. $\square$
Corollary: $(\forall x, x\in A \iff x\in B)\implies A=B$ 
proof: Find an upper bound $n$ of $A$, which is also an upper bound to $B$ since $B$ is extensionally identical to $A$. Now apply your Comprehension axiom to infer $\exists!X, \forall y, y\in X \iff (y\leq n\land y\in A)$, therefore $\exists!X, \forall y, y\in X \iff y\in A$. Since both $A$ and $B$ satisfy in place of $X$, then $A=B$ via uniqueness. $\square$
